# Converting pandas dataframe to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Pandas dataframe of which each column specifies an element of a datetime (year, month, day, etc.) in integer format. I want to join these separate columns into a single datetime object, which according to [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) is a legal operation. But after one frustrating hour I haven't yet figured out how to do this. See for instance this minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[2011, 5, 3], [2014, 9, 13], [2022, 1, 1]],
    columns=("year", "month", "day")
)

datetime = df.apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Desired result:

```
0 2011-05-03
1 2014-09-13
2 2022-01-01
```

Actual result:

```
                           year              ...                                        day
0 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002011              ...              1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000003
1 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002014              ...              1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000013
2 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002022              ...              1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pd.to_datetime` will properly parse dates from column names. Additionally you can have `'hour'`, `'minute'`, `'second'`, `'millisecond'`, `'microsecond'`, and/or '`nanosecond'` columns.

```
pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']])
0   2011-05-03
1   2014-09-13
2   2022-01-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

The column naming is insensitive to capitalization/pluralization and named columns can be specified in any order.

```
df['MiNuTEs'] = 2
pd.to_datetime(df[['MiNuTEs', 'month', 'year', 'day']])

0   2011-05-03 00:02:00
1   2014-09-13 00:02:00
2   2022-01-01 00:02:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Your solution seems elegant, but I get a `KeyError: ('year', 'month', 'day')` for your first example

Comment: @MPA check that you have `[[ ]]` so that you are passing the DataFrame. That error seems to indicate you only have a single bracket and are trying to do `df['year', 'month', 'day']`

Answer (score 2):

One way is joining the columns and then parsing with `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df.astype(str).apply('/'.join, axis=1).apply(pd.to_datetime)

0   2011-05-03
1   2014-09-13
2   2022-01-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[2011, 5, 3], [2014, 9, 13], [2022, 1, 1]],
    columns=("year", "month", "day")
)

result = df.apply(lambda r: pd.Timestamp(year=r.year, month=r.month, day=r.day), axis=1)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
0   2011-05-03
1   2014-09-13
2   2022-01-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```